# PHP - Session variables not saving from page to page

Tags: php, session, session-variables, web-hosting

BEFORE YOU MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE, I have read through all the answers on this topic and Non of them worked for me, this is why I am posting this.

So the problem is that the data for $_SESSION is not saving from page to page. Here is my test:

TestOne.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["user_id"] = 1;


if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
      header("Location: TestTwo.php");
}

?>
```

TestTwo.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["user_id"];
}


?>
```

It goes to page two but it is a blank page. Why is the data not saving from page to page?
session_save in the php.ini is set to /tmp (I am using hostgator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are missing `session_start();` on  your **`TestTwo.php`**

FYI : You need to call `session_start();` on all of your PHP files, if you are making use of Sessions.

> I have read through all the answers on this topic and Non of them
>   worked for me, this is why I am posting this.

Really caught my attention btw.

Answer (score 2):

for using session variables, u need to use `session_start()`
 before that

```
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["user_id"];
 }
```

Comment: yesvoteless as Bhadra says you need a session_start() at the beginning of EVERY page

Answer (score 1):

You need `session_start()` on every page that requires the session.